# Conditional grouping pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a DataFrame that has below columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Abe', 'Karl', 'Billy', 'Abe', 'Karl', 'Billy', 'Abe', 'Karl', 'Billy'], 
               'Lenght': ['10', '12.5', '11', '12.5', '12', '11', '12.5', '10', '5'],
              'Try': [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2],
              'Batch':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
```

In each `batch` a `name` gets arbitrary many tries to get the greatest `lenght.` 
What I want to do is create a column `win` that has the value 1 for greatest `lenght` in a `batch` and 0 otherwise, with the following conditions.

- If one  `name` hold the greatest `lenght` in a batch in multiple `try` only the first `try` will have the value 1 in `win`(See "Abe in example above")
- If two separate `name` holds equal greatest `lenght` then both will have value 1 in `win`

What I have managed to do so far is:

```
df.groupby(['Batch', 'name'])['lenght'].apply(lambda x: (x == x.max()).map({True: 1, False: 0}))
```

But it doesn't support all the conditions, any insight would be highly

Expected outout:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Abe', 'Karl', 'Billy', 'Abe', 'Karl', 'Billy', 'Abe', 'Karl', 'Billy'], 
                   'Lenght': ['10', '12.5', '11', '12.5', '12', '11', '12.5', '10', '5'],
                  'Try': [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2],
                  'Batch':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                  'win':[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]})
```

appreciated.
Many thanks,

Comment: It's "Length", not "Lenght".

Comment: @cs95 you are spot on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for `max` values per groups compared by `Lenght` column by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for equality and for map to `True->1` and `False->0` cast values to integers by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
#added first row data by second row
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Karl', 'Karl', 'Billy', 'Abe', 'Karl', 'Billy', 'Abe', 'Karl', 'Billy'], 
               'Lenght': ['12.5', '12.5', '11', '12.5', '12', '11', '12.5', '10', '5'],
              'Try': [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2],
              'Batch':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
```

---

```
df['Lenght'] = df['Lenght'].astype(float)


m1 = df.groupby('Batch')['Lenght'].transform('max').eq(df['Lenght'])

df1 = df[m1]
m2 = df1.groupby('Name')['Try'].transform('nunique').eq(1)
m3 = ~df1.duplicated(['Name','Batch'])

df['new'] = ((m2 | m3) & m1).astype(int)
print (df)
    Name  Lenght  Try  Batch  new
0   Karl    12.5    0      0    1
1   Karl    12.5    0      0    1
2  Billy    11.0    0      0    0
3    Abe    12.5    1      0    1
4   Karl    12.0    1      0    0
5  Billy    11.0    1      0    0
6    Abe    12.5    2      0    0
7   Karl    10.0    2      0    0
8  Billy     5.0    2      0    0
```

Comment: Thank you for you input, but your output doesn't support all the conditions. Is there something I could do to clear the question up? Thank you!

Comment: @MisterButter - Can you be more specific?

Comment: @MisterButter - Can you add expected output DataFrame?

Comment: @jezreal Will do!

Comment: @jezreal, Added!

Comment: @MisterButter - Second condition is `If two separate name holds equal greatest lenght then both will have value 1 in win` - it is not rows 3 and 6 with `Abe   12.5` ?

Comment: @jezreal That condition is for row 1 and 3 with `Abe 12.5` and `Karl 12.5`. What you are refering to is the first condition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208792/discussion-between-jezrael-and-misterbutter).